# Unable to start Flink JobManager container in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-flink

I am unable to start a Flink JobManager Docker container on M1 MacBook running Monterey. Below is the docker command pulled from the Flink [Docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/docker/) and the resulting **java.io.IOException**

```
docker run \
        --rm \
        --name=jobmanager \
        --network flink-network \
        --publish 8081:8081 \
        --env FLINK_PROPERTIES="${FLINK_PROPERTIES}" \
        flink:1.16.0-scala_2.12 jobmanager

INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint down with application status FAILED. Diagnostics java.io.IOException: Could not create the working directory /tmp/jm_ba47b82cf8d85068faa1c41d30126b5d.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.WorkingDirectory.createDirectory(WorkingDirectory.java:58)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.WorkingDirectory.<init>(WorkingDirectory.java:39)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.WorkingDirectory.create(WorkingDirectory.java:88)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointUtils.lambda$createJobManagerWorkingDirectory$2(ClusterEntrypointUtils.java:241)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.DeterminismEnvelope.map(DeterminismEnvelope.java:49)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointUtils.createJobManagerWorkingDirectory(ClusterEntrypointUtils.java:239)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.initializeServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:356)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:232)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:229)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:729)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.main(StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.java:59)
```

My docker version is:

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.22
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.9
 Git commit:        3a2c30b
 Built:             Thu Dec 15 22:28:41 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

Why does the container not allow creating the required directory?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was related to disk space issue. Running docker system prune cleared some space and the container is running nicely.